# UIButtonLabel Frame Width Wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

So like the title says, I have a UIButton which is giving its length as 0 when I use `self.titleLabel.frame.size.width`, however when I pause execution at the same line as the log statement that prints that out to the console, and instead print the object out using `po self.titleLabel`, it gives my frame as (24.5, 9; 190, 22.5), so a width of 190, not 0.

Does anyone know how or why these two values would differ from each other? And how I can get my code to read the correct width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured the answer out. After setting the title of the label (effectively happens when the view was loaded since it's all in storyboard) AutoLayout doesn't update the width of views until the next drawing cycle.

So, to fix this, I simply added `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` followed by `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` right before the code I needed the width for in order to force AutoLayout to set the width of my view when I needed it to.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using autolayout? autolayout places elements and follow constraints after the object is created (ie. ViewDidLoad, when you get the first values) and before you get the chance to customise the layout with the method you override in order to.